# Entity framework and storing japanese text

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

Is it possible to store english and japanese in the same field? The field is of type NVARCHAR(1024). The only thing that i see are question marks.

I added another field to the table and set it's collation to japanese. That seems to work. But i don't want 2 columns, i want just 1.

Everywhere i read that NVARCHAR can hold unicode without changing the default collation, is that true and if so how do i tell EF it's english or japanese?

Comment: Note to self: staring at the screen for too long doesn't improve your problemsolving ability. The only column giving problems wasn't Nvarchar after all. After changing it the problem went away and everything worked automagically as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the encryption of the string that you would like to save in DB by the entity-framework and then decide where you will save it!

To handle this issue, I suggest you use Encoding.GetEncoding Method (String) to make it.

Here is a function for you and you may test it and let me know if it works.

```
public static bool IsUnicode(string input)
{
    foreach (char chr in input)
    {
        string str = chr.ToString();
        Encoding code = Encoding.GetEncoding("GB18030");
        if (code.GetByteCount(str) == 2)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
And here is my test result: 

string zh = "微软";
string en = "Microsoft";
bool Izh = IsUnicode(zh);   //return false
bool Ien = IsUnicode(en);   //return true
```

To the parameter in the method, you could visit the MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/aa332097(VS.71).aspx to get the right string.

Best Regards,
Nader SGHIR